How to find the closest match in a datetime list?
I'm new in python and I have a list of dates as shown below.
'2021-01-23 06:14:16'
'2021-01-23 06:14:17'
'2021-01-23 06:19:35'
'2021-01-23 07:05:03'
'2021-01-23 07:05:04'
'2021-01-23 07:05:33'
'2021-01-23 07:05:34'

What I'm looking for is to remove the dates with the closest times and save it in a CSV file:
'2021-01-23 06:14:16'
#####'2021-01-23 06:14:17'
'2021-01-23 06:19:35'
'2021-01-23 07:05:03'
#####'2021-01-23 07:05:04'
'2021-01-23 07:05:33'
#####'2021-01-23 07:05:34'

Resulting in something like this:
'2021-01-23 06:14:16'
'2021-01-23 06:19:35'
'2021-01-23 07:05:03'
'2021-01-23 07:05:33'

I have tried with this code, but it doesn't work correctly. Could someone help me
data_detections = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')
date_detec = data_detections.Fecha_UTC.values.tolist()
time_detec = data_detections.Hora_UTC.values.tolist()
com_date = data_detections.Fecha_UTC.values.tolist()
com_time = data_detections.Hora_UTC.values.tolist()

file_csv = open('path/to/file2.csv', "w")
file_csv.write('Fecha_UTC,Hora_UTC\n')

for t1,d1 in zip(time_detec,date_detec):
    h1 = "".join(t1[0:2])
    m1 = "".join(t1[3:5])
    s1 = "".join(t1[6:])
    tm_comp = d1+','+h1+':'+m1
    for t2,d2 in zip(com_time,com_date):
        h2 = "".join(t2[0:2])
        m2 = "".join(t2[3:5])
        s2 = "".join(t2[6:])
        dd = "".join(d2[8:])  
        mm = "".join(d2[5:7])
        yy = "".join(d2[0:4])
        time_UTC = d2+','+h2+':'+m2
        
        if tm_comp == time_UTC:
            if s1 == s2:
                pass
            elif int(s2)-10 < int(s1) < int(s2)+10:
                if s1 == s2:
                    print('Same')
            elif int(s1)-10 < int(s2) < int(s1)+10:
                if s1 != s2:
                    print(tm_comp+':'+str(s1))
                    file_csv.write(tm_comp+':'+str(s1)+'\n')
        else:
            continue


Instead of parsing the strings manually, you probably want to convert them into datetime objects using the datetime module, and then check if the timedelta between two objects is < some threshold.  I will try to write up an example in an answer when I have an opportunity later.

Your examples show a list of strings but your code appears to work on a CSV file with two columns. Which is it? The simple and obvious approach would be to parse these into datetime objects and examine their timedelta pairwise instead of what you are doing. Will you want the smallest timedelta to be removed, or everything below some threshold, or, say, the n smallest values?

Also, if you don't use it for anything else, depending on Pandas just for its CSV reader seems like serious overkill.

@tripleee Pandas seems like a great tool for the job actually, they're just not using it effectively.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I'm looking at the code and seems like you don't want "the closest" per se, you want within 10 seconds, is that right? In that case the title isn't helpful at all. Please read [ask] for tips and [edit] to clarify.

Yeah, it cuts both ways; drop the dependency, or actually use the features of Pandas. I don't think this problem particularly requires Pandas unless the real data set is huge.

To read the data as datetimes, it looks like you can use pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', parse_dates=[['Fecha_UTC', 'Hora_UTC']])

FWIW, Pandas has DataFrame.to_csv(), so if you can get the filtering logic figured out, you can use that instead of having to do it manually.

Thank you for your advice, I'm aware that my code is not the best, which is why I keep learning. Thank you all

Your code suggests that the input CSV file actually looks like this:
Fecha,Hora
2021-01-23,06:14:16
2021-01-23,06:14:17
2021-01-23,06:19:35
2021-01-23,07:05:03
2021-01-23,07:05:04
2021-01-23,07:05:33
2021-01-23,07:05:34

If that is the case then using pandas feels like overkill as the requirement is very simple and could be implemented like this:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

INFILE = Path("foo.csv")
OUTFILE = Path("foo_out.csv")
FMT = "%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M:%S"
PARSE = datetime.strptime
DIFF = timedelta(seconds=10)


with INFILE.open("r") as infile:
    header = next(infile)
    lines = {k: PARSE(k, FMT) for k in map(str.rstrip, infile)}
    keys = list(lines.keys())
    for a, b in zip(keys, keys[1:]):
        if lines[a] and abs(lines[a] - lines[b]) < DIFF:
            lines[b] = None  # type: ignore
    with OUTFILE.open("w") as outfile:
        outfile.write(header)
        for k, _ in filter(lambda v: v[1] is not None, lines.items()):
            print(k, file=outfile)

This would produce:
Fecha,Hora
2021-01-23,06:14:16
2021-01-23,06:19:35
2021-01-23,07:05:03
2021-01-23,07:05:33

